# Bind a radiobutton to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, radio-button

I have a pageBlockTable that gets its items from a database list from the controller

I'm trying to add in that pageblockTable a column for radiobuttons so the user can select only one **row**.

I tried this but the radiobuttons are not binded together(I can select more than one item)

```
     apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myContacts}" var="c" id="agents" style="margin-top:1em; width:880px">



            <apex:column >
              <apex:facet name="header"></apex:facet>
                <apex:selectRadio label="selectRadio" id="selectRadio" layout="pageDirection" value="{!c.selected}">

            </apex:selectRadio>
        </apex:column>

       <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">Agent Details</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!c.con.LastName}" />
       </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

my controller

```
public List<cContact> myContacts {get;set;}


 public class cContact {  
    public Contact con {get; set;}  
    public boolean selected {get; set;}  


    public cContact(Contact c) {  
        con = c;  
        selected = false;  
    }  
}
```

**EDIT**
I also tried this

```
<apex:selectOptions value="{!items}" />
```

controller

```
 public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 

        for(cContact c :myContacts)
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption('','')); 

        }


        return options; 
    }
```

but all the **radio buttons were in one row.**

Comment: It's asinine that the `apex:selectRadio` component works in this way, all it needs is a `name` attribute.  I'm not sure how they missed the ability to group radio buttons freely.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue as you. Were you able to figure this out? Thanks.

Comment: @user3708392 check the answers below!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I used an html radio button for that.

```
    <apex:column >
 <apex:facet name="header"></apex:facet>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="{!c.con.Id}" />
 </apex:column>
```

and I passed the selected radio button from my command button like this

```
<apex:commandButton onclick="getSelectedContact();"
    value="next" id="btn3"
    rerender="Msgs">
</apex:commandButton>
<apex:actionFunction name="next" action="{!next}" rerender="Msgs">
    <apex:param name="selected" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>
<script>
 function getSelectedContact()
        {

            var $radio = $('input[name=group1]:checked');
            var updateDay = $radio.val();
            var id = $radio.attr('id');

             next(id);

        }
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

In my controller. I get the selected contact ID like this

```
 //get selected contact
   string Id = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('selected');
```

Comment: Great Solution, Please can you explain me how in the controller you get the value chosen.
I need to get the id of the record chosen.

Comment: @Enry Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of `<apex:inputCheckbox>` is somewhat lamentable, [but you could use the technique I described in a blog post](http://www.laceysnr.com/2013/04/checking-boxes-geting-input.html). It does use checkboxes instead, but you'd only need a tiny amount of javascript to ensure only on box is selected at a time that could be fired from an `onChange` event.

Basically the idea is you have a map of record ID to boolean, and as you iterate over your records down the page you can bind checkboxes to this map using dynamic binding:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!theMap[c.Id]}" styleClass="radio" onChange="clearOthers(this);"/>
```

Where `clearOthers()` is a javascript funciton which unchecks all checkboxes with the class `radio` and then selectes the element passed to it.

This isn't th neatest solution when you want radio buttons but I just wanted to show an alternative to the method that @raym0nd proposed, though I'd likely use his in reality.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Salesforce [example](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectRadio.htm). Basically you need to populate the selectRadio tag via the selectOptions parameter.

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!controllerBackingField}">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!possibleValues}"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
```

Comment: I tried that but my radio buttons were all in one row.

Comment: You may need to use regular HTML and JavaScript then.